# i want to show deprecated API list on iOS 17 using xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I want to know **Deprecated API list on iOS 17** !

Is there a way to know the deprecated api list on iOS 17 I used using Xcode and Development Tools?

Answer (score 0):

There is no list of deprecated APIs from Apple. If you want to fix deprecated markdown on your project, you have to go through it step by step and fix it case by case. In the past, there was documentation for comparing between iOS versions. However, it's no longer support since iOS 11, you can check this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008244-SW1). Nowadays we just have [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-17-release-notes). You have to check for yourself. And also [change log](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) file from Swift repo if you don't know.